# Simple way to split and joiin a string with Object Initializer?

Tags: c#, csv, logging

Is there a way to shorten this code below. (expecting 20+ values)
The values will always remain in the same order.

```
string[] values = line.Split(',');
LogEntry entry = new LogEntry()
{
    Id = values[0],
    Service = values[1],
    Name = values[2],
    Process = values[3],
    type = values[4]
    [...]
};
```

Comment: The code is pretty "short" already.  There's no repetition.  What's wrong with it?

Comment: It's works fine, but I'm just currious if there is a prettier way of structuring this kind of code snippet. As it is now, I have to assign all values the same way ->  `Something = values[25];`

Comment: I guess you could create a constructor on `LogEntry` which accepts the string or the array, so consuming code need only call that constructor.  But if you have 25 properties to assign then you're going to have 25 assignments.  There's really no way around that.  Even if you find some really clever hack to arbitrarily reduce the number of keystrokes, is the less supportable code really worth it?

Comment: Yes I see the problem, the code must be defined somewhere actually. I was thinking about some way with an enum, iterating through it, and automatically assigning the values to the object. Just out of curiosity I came across that question, maybe there was a LINQ syntax or something cool.

Answer (score 1):

I personally do not know of a simplified way of doing this -- somewhere this code would need to exist. However, you could use a mapper solution like AutoMapper to set up a mapping. At least this your handlers or actions aren't bloated with assignment logic.

Hope this helps a bit.

Looking forward to reading other answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can add to `LogEntry` constructor with one param `string line` and move logic into constructor.

Then code will be look like

```
LogEntry entry = new LogEntry(line);
```

And in constructor something like this:

```
public void LogEntry(string line)
{
    string[] values = line.Split(',');
    Id = values[0],
    Service = values[1],
    Name = values[2],
    Process = values[3],
    type = values[4]
    [...]    
}
```

This code must be somewhere. 
Is it better solution depends on the situation. If you often used the object initializer that will greatly simplify the code. If you do not it's probably not have much of a difference.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, you are trying to avoid those twenty lines of setting the values. How about using a reflection based solution like the one below ?

```
string[] values = line.Split(',');
var orderedLogEntryPropertyNames = 
new string[]{ "Id", "Name", "Process" }; 
//list all the LogEntry property names in the order that map to the values
var logEntry = new LogEntry();
var logEntryProperties = typeof(LogEntry).GetProperties();
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
  {
    var propertyToSet = 
    logEntryProperties.First(p => p.Name.Equals(orderedLogEntryPropertyNames[i]));
    propertyToSet.SetValue(logEntry, values[i]);
   }
```